# Retrieving a HashMap

Tags: jpa, dictionary, hashmap, eclipselink, jpql

A entity containing a HashMap (annotated with ElementCollection) will be persisted using Eclipse Link / JPA.

By using the following JPQL query the HashMap should be retrivied now:

```
SELECT t.myMap FROM myEntity t WHERE t.id = :id"
```

Unfortunately the result is not the Map again, but a list of Strings which are (only) the values of the HashMap.

How can I get the HashMap as a single result?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  What you are asking for is not the collection in the entity, but elements from the join.  The best you might get is to query for the entity and use its getMyMap() to get the collection you are after

Comment: Unfortunately this method doesn't exist in the entity - it should be not possible for users of a object of myEntity to directly access the Map. If I would add such a method, I must give it the visibility public. Is there no other way the get the content of the collection?

Comment: In JPA you have to get each item from the relationship and build the map yourself.  EclipseLink does allow setting a ContainerPolicy type to use for queries, but it the EJBQueryImpl only defines getResultList or getResultCollection, neither can return a Map so you would need to execute the query using native EclipseLink api.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to use the native EclipseLink api?